# Generic Error in GDI+ when calling Bitmap.getHBitmap()

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi, gdi+

I'm writing an application which as part of it draws an image on a Logitech G15v2 keyboard's LCD.  For the most part the function works fine, but after a while of running, one of the lines throws a "`Generic Error in GDI+`"

The problem, according to a stack trace, is in `Bitmap.GetHbitmap()`:

```
at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetHbitmap(Color background)
at System.Drawing.Bitmap.GetHbitmap()
    at CSCI171_TermProject.G15.Tick(Single Interval) in C:\Users\Sukasa\CSCI171\Term Project\CSCI171-TermProject\G15.vb:line 45"
```

I've read a few threads mentioning this error, but that was in the context of *saving* a file, not getting its associated HBitmap.  Would anyone with more experience with GDI+ than me be able to offer any ideas to what causes this problem?

For better reference, here's the full code module:

```
Public Module G15
    Private G15 As New G15Lib.G15Interface
    Private G15BaseImage As New Bitmap("GFX\G15-BGImg.png")
    Private G15Minimap As New Bitmap(43, 43, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Private G15HeartMonitor As New Bitmap(44, 17, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    Private G15Heartbeat As New Bitmap("GFX\G15-HB.png")
    Private G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(G15BaseImage)
    Private G15On As Boolean = False

    Public Sub Init()
        If Not G15.G15Detected Then
            Log.Write("Get extra content by connecting a G15")
            Return
        End If
        G15On = True
        G15.LCD.initLCD(AppName)
        G15.LEDs.setKeyboardLight(2)
        G15.LCD.showBitmap(G15BaseImage.GetHbitmap, 1)
        Log.Write("Logitech G15 Features Enabled")
    End Sub

    Public Sub Tick(ByVal Interval As Single)
        Const StepTime As Single = 0.09
        If Not G15On Then Return

        Static HeartTime As Single = StepTime
        HeartTime -= Interval
        If HeartTime <= 0 Then
            HeartTime = StepTime
            AnimateHeartbeat()
        End If

        MakeMinimap()

        G.DrawImage(G15Minimap, New Rectangle(0, 0, 43, 43), New Rectangle(0, 0, 43, 43), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        G.DrawImage(G15HeartMonitor, New Rectangle(116, 0, 44, 17), New Rectangle(0, 0, 44, 17), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        Try
            G15.LCD.showBitmap(G15BaseImage.GetHbitmap, 1)
        Catch ex As Exception
            G15On = False
            G15.LCD.closeLCD()
            Log.Write("GDI+ Error in G15 renderer")
            Log.Write("G15 features disabled")
        End Try

    End Sub

    Public Sub AnimateHeartbeat()
        Static G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(G15HeartMonitor)
        Static BMTemp As New Bitmap(44, 17, Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
        Static GTemp As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMTemp)
        Dim Columns As Integer = 13 + ((PlayerActor.HPMax - PlayerActor.iHP) / PlayerActor.HPMax) * 20
        Static ColumnIndex As Integer = 0

        GTemp.DrawImage(G15HeartMonitor, New Rectangle(0, 0, 44, 17), New Rectangle(1, 0, 44, 17), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
        G.DrawImage(BMTemp, New Rectangle(0, 0, 44, 17), New Rectangle(0, 0, 44, 17), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        G.DrawLine(Pens.Black, 43, 0, 43, 17)

        If ColumnIndex >= Columns Then
            ColumnIndex = 0
        End If

        G.DrawImage(G15Heartbeat, New Rectangle(43, 4, 1, 8), New Rectangle(If(PlayerActor.iHP > 0, Math.Min(ColumnIndex, 7), 7), 0, 1, 8), GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

        ColumnIndex += 1
    End Sub

    Public Sub MakeMinimap()
        Static oPos As New XYPos(0, 0)
        Dim iActorIndice As Int32 = 0

        For Y = -21 To 21
            For X = -21 To 21

                G15Minimap.SetPixel(X + 21, Y + 21, Color.Black)
                oPos.X = X + PlayerActor.PositionX
                oPos.Y = Y + PlayerActor.PositionY
                If oPos.Y < 0 OrElse oPos.X < 0 OrElse oPos.X >= iMapSize OrElse oPos.Y >= iMapSize Then
                    G15Minimap.SetPixel(X + 21, Y + 21, Color.Black)
                    Continue For
                End If
                If Main.Map.arrAccessiblityMap(oPos.AsOffset) Then
                    G15Minimap.SetPixel(X + 21, Y + 21, Color.White)
                Else
                    G15Minimap.SetPixel(X + 21, Y + 21, Color.Black)
                End If

                For iActorIndice = iActorIndice To genActors.Count - 1
                    Dim oActor As Actor = genActors(iActorIndice)
                    If oPos.Y > oActor.PositionY Then
                        Continue For
                    ElseIf oPos.Y < oActor.PositionY Then
                        Exit For
                    ElseIf oPos.Y = oActor.PositionY AndAlso oPos.X < oActor.PositionX Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                    If oPos.X = oActor.PositionX AndAlso oPos.Y = oActor.PositionY Then
                        G15Minimap.SetPixel(X + 21, Y + 21, Color.Black)
                    End If
                Next

            Next
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start out by making sure that .Dispose() is correctly called on Graphics and Bitmap objects. (I don't understand the purpose of all those Statics' - but that's another story).

Comment: .Dispose() isn't called on any Graphics of Bitmap objects, but that's because over the lifetime of the program, none of them are destroyed, so I have no reason to call that.

Comment: Actually I'm going to go ahead and mark your answer correct because thinking about it pointed me to something you didn't mentioned but of a similar vein: I wasn't deleting the GDI HBitmap objects!

Comment: Thnx! (I was thinking about the three objects within AnimateHeartbeat!)

Answer (score 0):

After calling `GetHbitmap()`, you need to call `DeleteObject()`

http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/gdi32/DeleteObject.html