# GDI+ Error when calling Image.FromHBitmap on handle returned by LoadImage

Tags: c#, gdi+, loadimage

So I try to load an image resource from a dll file. To do this I created the method

```
static Bitmap GetImageResource(IntPtr handle, string resourceId)
{
    IntPtr img_ptr = NativeMethods.LoadImage(handle, "#" + resourceId, IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16, 0);

    if (img_ptr == IntPtr.Zero)
        throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception((int)NativeMethods.GetLastError());

    return Image.FromHbitmap(img_ptr);
}
```

Which loads the image resource from the dll, given a handle and the resource id. According to [this question I asked yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39507459/c-sharp-loadimage-returns-error-1813/39508560#39508560) I have to prepend a # to the id, which I did. Now the handle returned by LoadImage is not zero anymore, however when I try to create Bitmap image from this handle using
`Image.FromHbitmap` I get a `System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException` saying

> A generic error occurred in GDI+

(or something similar, I dont get the message in english so I roughly translated it)

I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286722/generic-error-in-gdi-when-calling-bitmap-gethbitmap) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053052/a-generic-error-occurred-in-gdi-jpeg-image-to-memorystream) question but they didn't help me.

Why is this? Thanks in advance

Comment: That is entirely normal, you are loading an icon, not an image.  Use Icon.FromHandle() instead.  You'll have to destroy the icon again with DestroyIcon, later, after you are sure the Icon object cannot be used again.

Answer (score 0):

If the Dll is a .NET assembly, you can call [`Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt(v=vs.110).aspx), like so:

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromAssemblyPath(string assemblyPath, string resourceId) {
    Assembly assemb = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
    Stream stream = assemb.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceId);
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
    return bmp;
}
```

If it is a native dll (not an assembly), you will have to use Interop instead. You have a solution [here](http://dedjo.blogspot.com.es/2008/01/how-to-load-unmanaged-native-resources.html), and could be summarized as follows:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string lpFileName, IntPtr hFile, uint dwFlags);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
static extern IntPtr FindResource(IntPtr hModule, int lpID, string lpType); 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern IntPtr LoadResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo); 

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)] 
static extern uint SizeofResource(IntPtr hModule, IntPtr hResInfo);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

static const int LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002;

public static Bitmap getImageFromNativeDll(string dllPath, string resourceName, int resourceId) {
    Bitmap bmp = null;
    IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibraryEx(dllPath, IntPtr.Zero, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
    IntPtr resourceHandle = FindResource(dllHandle, resourceId, resourceName);
    uint resourceSize = SizeofResource(dllHandle, resourceHandle); 
    IntPtr resourceUnmanagedBytesPtr = LoadResource(dllHandle, resourceHandle);

    byte[] resourceManagedBytes = new byte[resourceSize]; 
    Marshal.Copy(resourceUnmanagedBytesPtr, resourceManagedBytes, 0, (int)resourceSize); 
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(resourceManagedBytes)) {
        bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(m);
    }

    FreeLibrary(dllHandle);

    return bmp;
}
```

*No error handling was added, this is **not** production-ready code.*

NOTE: Should you need an Icon, you can use the Icon constructor that receives a stream:

```
    using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream(resourceManagedBytes)) {
        bmp = (Icon)new Icon(m);
    }
```

And you should change the return type accordingly.

Comment: What exactly is `bptr`?

Comment: A typo. I've changed the code with the proper variable name.

Comment: I only have the ID of the resource, what should I use for the `resourceName` parameter?

Comment: Use `string.Format("#{0}", ID)`
That is, `"#ID"`

Comment: `resourceUnmanagedBytesPtr` does still contain a null pointer

Comment: What happens when you pass a null resource name, and just pass the resource Id as int?